# Adding 1 table to .edmx file in EF6 with visual studio 2012 changes the entire file and creates 100s of errros

Tags: entity-framework-6

When I open the .edmx file and do "Update Model from Database" and then select just 1 table to add it ends up changing hundreds of objects and creating hundreds of errors.